# CsvHelper - Read different record types in same CSV

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm trying to read two types of records out of a CSV file with the following structure:

```
PlaceName,Longitude,Latitude,Elevation
NameString,123.456,56.78,40

Date,Count
1/1/2012,1
2/1/2012,3
3/1/2012,10
4/2/2012,6
```

I know this question has been covered previously in

- [Reading multiple classes from single csv file using CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057465/reading-multiple-classes-from-single-csv-file-using-csvhelper)
- [Multiple Record Types in One File?](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/441)

but when I run my implementation it gets a `CsvMissingFieldException` saying that `Fields 'Date' do not exist in the CSV file`. I have two definition and map classes, one for the location and the other for the counts, which are:

```cs
public class LocationDefinition
{
    public string PlaceName { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Elevation { get; set; }
}

public sealed class LocationMap : CsvClassMap<LocationDefinition>
{
    public LocationMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.PlaceName).Name("PlaceName");
        Map(m => m.Longitude).Name("Longitude");
        Map(m => m.Latitude).Name("Latitude");
        Map(m => m.Elevation).Name("Elevation");
    }            
}     

public class CountDefinition
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CountMap : CsvClassMap<CountDefinition>
{
    public CountMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Date).Name("Date");
        Map(m => m.Count).Name("Count");
    }
}
```

The code that I have for reading the csv file is:

```cs
LocationDefinition Location;
var Counts = new List<CountDefinition>();

using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(@"Path\To\CsvFile"))
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(fileReader))
{
    csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<LocationMap>();
    csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CountMap>();

    // Only reads a single line of Location data
    csvReader.Read();
    LocationData = csvReader.GetRecord<LocationDefinition>();
    csvReader.Read(); // skip blank line
    csvReader.Read(); // skip second header section

    // Read count data records
    while (csvReader.Read())
    {
        var tempCount = csvReader.GetRecord<CountDefinition>();
        Counts.Add(tempCount);
    }
}
```

The exception gets thrown on the `tempCount` line. From what I can tell it still expects a Location record, but I would have thought `GetRecord<CountDefinition>` would specify the record type. I've also tried `ClearRecordCache` and unregistering the `LocationMap` to no avail.

How should this code be changed to get it to read a csv file of this structure?

Comment: Does the structure repeat?  Can you post more than one structure.  Been parsing fils like this for 40 years and can easily give a great solution.

Comment: The location section only occurs once and will be before the count section (currently it only has one record), the count section can have any number of records. It might be worth making the code capable of handling any number of location records.

Comment: I'd chop the file in two where the CRLF appears.  Once it has the Location def initialized I cant get it to let go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response from Josh Close on the issue tracker:

[CsvReader not recognising different registered class maps](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/551)

Here is his answer to this question:

> Since you don't have a single header, you'll need to ignore headers
>   and use indexes instead. This brings up an idea though. I could have
>   the ReadHeader method parse headers for a specific record type.
>
> Here is an example that should work for you though.
>
> ```cs
> void Main()
> {
>     LocationDefinition Location;
>     var Counts = new List<CountDefinition>();
>
>     using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
>     using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
>     using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
>     using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
>     {
>         writer.WriteLine("PlaceName,Longitude,Latitude,Elevation");
>         writer.WriteLine("NameString,123.456,56.78,40");
>         writer.WriteLine();
>         writer.WriteLine("Date,Count");
>         writer.WriteLine("1/1/2012,1");
>         writer.WriteLine("2/1/2012,3");
>         writer.WriteLine("3/1/2012,10");
>         writer.WriteLine("4/2/2012,6");
>         writer.Flush();
>         stream.Position = 0;
>
>         csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
>         csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<LocationMap>();
>         csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CountMap>();
>
>         csvReader.Read(); // get header
>         csvReader.Read(); // get first record
>         var locationData = csvReader.GetRecord<LocationDefinition>();
>
>         csvReader.Read(); // skip blank line
>         csvReader.Read(); // skip second header section
>
>         // Read count data records
>         while (csvReader.Read())
>         {
>             var tempCount = csvReader.GetRecord<CountDefinition>();         
>             Counts.Add(tempCount);
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> public class LocationDefinition
> {
>     public string PlaceName { get; set; }
>     public double Longitude { get; set; }
>     public double Latitude { get; set; }
>     public double Elevation { get; set; }
> }
>
> public sealed class LocationMap : CsvClassMap<LocationDefinition>
> {
>     public LocationMap()
>     {
>         Map(m => m.PlaceName);
>         Map(m => m.Longitude);
>         Map(m => m.Latitude);
>         Map(m => m.Elevation);
>     }
> }
>
> public class CountDefinition
> {
>     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
>     public int Count { get; set; }
> }
>
> public sealed class CountMap : CsvClassMap<CountDefinition>
> {
>     public CountMap()
>     {
>         Map(m => m.Date);
>         Map(m => m.Count);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    enum State
    {
        FIND_RECORD,
        GET_LOCATION,
        GET_DATES
    }
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            State state = State.FIND_RECORD;

            LocationDefinition location = null;
            string inputLine = "";
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length == 0)
                {
                    state = State.FIND_RECORD;
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.FIND_RECORD :
                            if (inputLine.StartsWith("PlaceName"))
                            {
                                state = State.GET_LOCATION;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (inputLine.StartsWith("Date"))
                                {
                                    state = State.GET_DATES;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case State.GET_DATES :
                            if (location.dates == null) location.dates = new CountDefinition();
                            location.dates.dates.Add(new CountDefinition(inputLine));
                            break;
                        case State.GET_LOCATION :
                            location = new LocationDefinition(inputLine);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class LocationDefinition
    {
        public static List<LocationDefinition> locations = new List<LocationDefinition>();
        public CountDefinition dates { get; set; }
        public string PlaceName { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Elevation { get; set; }

        public LocationDefinition(string location)
        {
            string[] array = location.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            PlaceName = array[0];
            Longitude = double.Parse(array[1]);
            Latitude = double.Parse(array[2]);
            Elevation = double.Parse(array[3]);
            locations.Add(this);
         }
    }



    public class CountDefinition
    {
        public List<CountDefinition> dates = new List<CountDefinition>();
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public CountDefinition() { ;}

        public CountDefinition(string count)
        {
            string[] array = count.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Date = DateTime.Parse(array[0]);
            Count = int.Parse(array[1]);
            dates.Add(this);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a fix for my CsvHelper code, though this is useful for anybody wanting to avoid an external library.

Comment: Why would anybody use a 3rd party app to simply read a text file when it can easily be done with the string split function?