# Custom File Parser

Tags: c#, parsing, text, csv

I am building a parser for a custom pipe delimited file format and I am finding my code to be very bulky, could someone suggest better methods of parsing this data?

The file's data is broken down by a line delimited by a pipe (|), each line starts with a record type, followed by an ID, followed by different number of columns after.

**Ex:** 
CDI|11111|OTHERDATA|somemore|other

CEX001|123131|DATA|data

CCC|123131|DATA|data1|data2|data3|data4|data5|data6

. I am splitting by pipe, then grabbing the first two columns, and then using a switch checking the first line and calling a function that will parse the remaining into an object purpose built for that record type. I would really like a more elegant method.

```
    public Dictionary<string, DataRecord> Parse()
    { 
        var data = new Dictionary<string, DataRecord>();

        var rawDataDict = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>();
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(_path))
        {
            var split = line.Split('|');
            var Id = split[1];
            if (!rawDataDict.ContainsKey(Id))
            {
                rawDataDict.Add(Id, new List<List<string>> {split.ToList()});
            }
            else
            {
                rawDataDict[Id].Add(split.ToList());
            }
        }

        rawDataDict.ToList().ForEach(pair =>
        {
            var key = pair.Key.ToString();
            var values = pair.Value;

            foreach (var value in values)
            {

                var recordType = value[0];

                switch (recordType)
                {
                    case "CDI":
                        var cdiRecord = ParseCdi(value);
                        if (!data.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            data.Add(key, new DataRecord
                            {
                                Id = key, CdiRecords = new List<CdiRecord>() {  cdiRecord }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data[key].CdiRecords.Add(cdiRecord);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "CEX015":
                        var cexRecord = ParseCex(value);
                        if (!data.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            data.Add(key, new DataRecord
                            {
                                Id = key,
                                CexRecords = new List<Cex015Record>() { cexRecord }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data[key].CexRecords.Add(cexRecord);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "CPH":
                        CphRecord cphRecord = ParseCph(value);
                        if (!data.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            data.Add(key, new DataRecord
                            {
                                Id = key,
                                CphRecords = new List<CphRecord>() { cphRecord }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data[key].CphRecords.Add(cphRecord);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: You could use the filehelper csvparser, and set the delimeter to | and then just read each line and work with it with a switch statement for the record type.. or whatever suits your fancy

Comment: FileHelper is made for a single file of the same format isn't it? I have multiple record types in a single file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515214/csvhelper-read-different-record-types-in-same-csv

Comment: That's even more bloated than what I have :(. Maybe I've found the best solution :(.

Comment: Depends if the code is more but faster I guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out FileHelper, here is your exact example - http://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/

Given you're data of

```
CDI|11111|OTHERDATA|Datas
CEX001|123131|DATA
CCC|123131
```

You could create a class to model this to allow FileHelpers to parse the delimited file:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class Record
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string[] Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Then we could allow FileHelpers to parse in to this object type:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Record>();
var records = engine.ReadFile("Input.txt");
```

After we've got all the records loaded in to `Record` objects we can use a bit of linq to pull them in to their given types

```
var cdis = records.Where(x => x.Type == "CDI")
                .Select(x => new Cdi(x.Fields[0], x.Fields[1], x.Fields[2])
                .ToArray();

var cexs = records.Where(x => x.Type == "CEX001")
                .Select(x => new Cex(x.Fields[0], x.Fields[1)
                .ToArray();

var cccs = records.Where(x => x.Type == "CCC")
                .Select(x => new Ccc(x.Fields[0])
                .ToArray();
```

You could also simplify the above using something like AutoMapper - http://automapper.org/

**Alternatively** you could use `ConditionalRecord` attributes which will only parse certain lines if they match a given criteria. This will however be slower the more record types you have but you're code will be cleaner and FileHelpers will be doing most of the heavy lifting:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
[ConditionalRecord(RecordCondition.IncludeIfMatchRegex, "^CDI")]
public class Cdi
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Data1 { get; set; }

    public string Data2 { get; set; }

    public string Data3 { get; set; }
}

[DelimitedRecord("|")]
[ConditionalRecord(RecordCondition.IncludeIfMatchRegex, "^CEX001")]
public class Cex001
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Data1 { get; set; }
}

[DelimitedRecord("|")]
[ConditionalRecord(RecordCondition.IncludeIfMatchRegex, "^CCC")]
public class Ccc
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}


            var input =
            @"CDI|11111|Data1|Data2|Data3
CEX001|123131|Data1
CCC|123131";

var CdiEngine = new FileHelperEngine<Cdi>();
var cdis = CdiEngine.ReadString(input);


var cexEngine = new FileHelperEngine<Cex001>();
var cexs = cexEngine.ReadString(input);

var cccEngine = new FileHelperEngine<Ccc>();
var cccs = cccEngine.ReadString(input);
```

Comment: The file has multiple record types in it, all at once, I don't believe this will work?

Comment: You're correct it doesn't support a discriminator to create multiple types of objects, you could however just load in to a common model and then split out using linq -`records.Type.where(x => x.Type == "CCC")` etc..

Comment: Unfortunately, the only thing they share is the first two records, after that each one is completely different. :(

Comment: It's still probably worth using `FileHelper` for the parsing.

Comment: How would I do that with the multiple record types in a single file? O.O

Comment: I'm sorry, I clarified the data format. There is a unique number of columns per data type, they do not share a common number of columns.

Comment: I've added a second example that uses `ConditionalRecord` attributes which allows you to select records from the document which might be helpful

Comment: Amazing, I will give this a try!

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop isn't really doing anything other than organizing your data differently.  You should be able to eliminate it and use the data as it is from the file.  Something like this should give you what you want:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(_path))
{
    var split = line.Split('|');
    var key = split[1];
    var value = split;


        var recordType = value[0];

        switch (recordType)
        {
            case "CDI":
                var cdiRecord = ParseCdi(value.ToList());
                if (!data.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    data.Add(key, new DataRecord
                    {
                        Id = key, CdiRecords = new List<CdiRecord>() {  cdiRecord }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    data[key].CdiRecords.Add(cdiRecord);
                }
                break;
            case "CEX015":
                var cexRecord = ParseCex(value.ToList());
                if (!data.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    data.Add(key, new DataRecord
                    {
                        Id = key,
                        CexRecords = new List<Cex015Record>() { cexRecord }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    data[key].CexRecords.Add(cexRecord);
                }
                break;
            case "CPH":
                CphRecord cphRecord = ParseCph(value.ToList());
                if (!data.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    data.Add(key, new DataRecord
                    {
                        Id = key,
                        CphRecords = new List<CphRecord>() { cphRecord }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    data[key].CphRecords.Add(cphRecord);
                }
                break;
        }
};
```

Caveat: This is just put together here and hasn't been properly checked for syntax.